# How to transfer mysql table to hive?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I have a large mysql table that I would like to transfer to a Hadoop/Hive table. Are there standard commands or techniques to transfer a simple (but large) table from Mysql to Hive? The table stores mostly analytics data.

Comment: http://oracleabc.com/b/archives/1428  perhaps?

Comment: @MarcB that link was super helpful tnx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. First of all download mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 and put the jar to lib and bin folder of Sqoop
2. **Create the table definition in Hive** with **exact field names and types** as in mysql

   sqoop import --verbose --fields-terminated-by ','  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --table employee --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --fields-terminated-by ',' --split-by id --hive-table employee

test                  - Database name

employee              - Table name (present in test)

/user/hive/warehouse  - Directory in HDFS where the data has to be imported

--split-by id         - id can be the primary key of the table 'employee'

--hive-table employee - employee table whose definition is present in Hive

[Sqoop User Guide](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html) (One of the best guide for learning Sqoop)

Answer (score 1):

[Apache Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) is a tool that solves this problem:

> Apache Sqoop(TM) is a tool designed for efficiently transferring bulk data between Apache Hadoop and structured datastores such as relational databases.