# data from mutiple mysql tables to hadoop map-reduce

Tags: java, mysql, hadoop, mapreduce

We have following scenario:

We have a chain of `map-reduce processes` implemented in java.Currently we are reading data from a mysql table and saving output to another `mysql table`.Now we may need data from another table as input to map/reduce process.

Possible Solutions:

a) Either we can have a join query for input to map process or

b) we can read needed data by making simple `jdbc connection` and requesting data again and again(although, i don't prefer it).

Questions:

What are the best practices in such scenario?
We may move to `mongoDB` in future.What will be best practice in that scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is not possible for now.

Answer (score 0):

[SQOOP](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopDevGuide.html) and [HIVE](http://hive.apache.org/) can be used.

You can use **SQOOP** for transfering data from mysql table to HDFS and then to **HIVE**.
From HIVE (after operations) , you can export the tables back to Mysql.

**Example :**

- First of all download mysql-connector-java-5.0.8 and put the jar to
  lib and bin folder of Sqoop
- Create the table definition in Hive with exact field names and types
  as in mysql

> sqoop import --verbose --fields-terminated-by ',' --connect
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --table employee --hive-import
>   --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --fields-terminated-by ',' --split-by id --hive-table employee

Follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632514/how-to-transfer-mysql-table-to-hive/8941132#8941132) for reference

Comment: We know about sqoop and hive but they are not related to our current scenario. We have to use core map-reduce processes due to project requirements. The question is how to get data in mapper-reducer from multiple sql tables?