# How to convert mysql DDL into hive DDL

Tags: hadoop, schema, translation, hive

Given a SQL script containing DDL for creating tables in MySQL database, I would like to convert the script into Hive DDL, so that I can create tables into hive. I could have written an interpreter myself, but thought there might be details I could miss (e.g. data format conversion, int, bigint, time, date, etc.) since I am very new to hive DDL.

I have seen this thread [How to transfer mysql table to hive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632514/how-to-transfer-mysql-table-to-hive), which mentioned sqoop http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh/3/sqoop/SqoopUserGuide.html. However, from what I see, sqoop certainly translate the DDL, but only as an intermediate step (thus the translated DDL is no where to be found). Am I missing the command that would output the translation with the MySQL DDL as an input?

For example, my MySQL DDL look like:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_keyword` (
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `keyword_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`keyword_id`),
  KEY `keyword_id` (`keyword_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `analyst_keywords_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`keyword_id`) REFERENCES `keywords` (`keyword_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the output Hive DDL would be like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_keyword (
  username string,
  keyword_id int,
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually thought this was not supported, but after looking at the Source here is what I saw in [HiveImport.java](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=sqoop.git;a=blob_plain;f=src/java/org/apache/sqoop/hive/HiveImport.java;hb=trunk):

```
/**
 * @return true if we're just generating the DDL for the import, but
 * not actually running it (i.e., --generate-only mode). If so, don't
 * do any side-effecting actions in Hive.
 */
private boolean isGenerateOnly() {
  return generateOnly;
}

/**
 * @return a File object that can be used to write the DDL statement.
 * If we're in gen-only mode, this should be a file in the outdir, named
 * after the Hive table we're creating. If we're in import mode, this should
 * be a one-off temporary file.
 */
private File getScriptFile(String outputTableName) throws IOException {
  if (!isGenerateOnly()) {
    return File.createTempFile("hive-script-", ".txt",
        new File(options.getTempDir()));
  } else {
    return new File(new File(options.getCodeOutputDir()),
        outputTableName + ".q");
  }
}
```

So  basically you should be able to do only the DDL generation using the option `--generate-only` used in cunjunction with `--outdir` and your table will be create in the output dir specified and named after your table.

For example based on the link you provided:

```
sqoop import --verbose --fields-terminated-by ',' --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/test --table employee --hive-import --warehouse-dir /user/hive/warehouse --fields-terminated-by ',' --split-by id --hive-table employee --outdir /tmp/mysql_to_hive/ddl --generate-only
```

will create `/tmp/mysql_to_hive/ddl/employee.q`

Comment: Thanks for the very useful info. Without installing sqoop, i ended up writing a simple interpreter which takes a script of mysql table create schema and prints the hive schema. From the java class you mentioned, I came to `org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveTypes` with mappings between sql type and hive.

Comment: Seems like there isn't such an option --generate-only available, at least not in Sqoop 1.4.5, which I'm using. Perhaps it was deprecated a while back? by examining the code I see that in order to use DDL generation with no importation, you need to use the codegen tool. It is not in the import tool - as all the HiveImport instances there are constructed with a hardcoded 'false' flag for generateOnly. The only place it is constructed with 'true' is in codegen, see here: http://www.codatlas.com/github.com/apache/sqoop/trunk/src/java/org/apache/sqoop/tool/CodeGenTool.java?line=123

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, one could use the **create-hive-table** tool to do that. The create-hive-table tool populates a Hive metastore with a definition for a table based on a database table previously imported to HDFS, or one planned to be imported. This effectively performs the **--hive-import** step of sqoop-import **without running** the preceeding import. For example,

> sqoop create-hive-table --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/demo
>   -username root --table t2 --fields-terminated-by  ',' --hive-table t2

This command will create a blank hive table t2 based on the schema of the same table in MySQL without importing the data.