# Convert Hive Table to MySQL

Tags: mysql, hive

I have a large Hive table which I would like to transfer from the server, to my local MySQL database. Are there any standard ways of doing this?

I downloaded the Hive file from the metastore and it appears to be in an unusual formate where it is difficult to parse to a database (The columns dont seem to even be seperated)

e.g. of file from hive:

```
"1980""007"59610.0016778523489932886"actors""007"59610.0016778523489932886"7d""007"59620.003355704697986577"abu""007"59610.0016778523489932886
```

Edit:
Heres my table

```
DESCRIBE phil_overall_cooc

0   tag_a   string  
1   tag_b   string  
2   bcount  bigint  
3   cooc    bigint  
4   prob    double
```

Comment: If your columns aren't separated that's going to be a problem. Can you share your table definition (you can use the Hive `describe` statement)?

Comment: Check my edit. I dont think they are, do you know how I can add a tab delimiter between columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sqoop is what you are looking for ! I'm using it to send my data into MySQL. The only trick is that you must use TEXTFILE without partitions from

```
file_format:
  : SEQUENCEFILE
  | TEXTFILE
  | RCFILE     (Note: only available starting with 0.6.0)
  | ORC        (Note: only available starting with 0.11.0)
  | INPUTFORMAT input_format_classname OUTPUTFORMAT output_format_classname
```

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Create%2FDrop%2FTruncateTable

If it's not in TEXTFILE, you can do a

> INSERT INTO TABLE tablename1 [PARTITION (partcol1=val1, partcol2=val2 ...)] select_statement1 FROM from_statement;

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries

Now that you have your export table, you may use sqoop as follow:

```
sqoop export 
  --connect ${YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING}
  --username ${YOUR_USERNAME} 
  --password ${YOUR_PASSWORD}
  --table ${MYSQL_TABLE_NAME}
  --update-key ${FIELD1[,FIELD2]*}
  --update-mode allowinsert 
  --export-dir ${PATH_TO_YOUR_HIVE_TABLE_ON_HDFS} 
  --input-fields-terminated-by \001 
  --num-mappers 1 
  --batch 
  --verbose
```

http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html#_syntax_3

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

- This [PDF](http://api.ning.com/files/GmgDk5*tdQIIzeiAIT*felDpELRWJvbShVfnCCCj0XYcEhoZOIggbt4t8ej13tNxQXWF5qKzoB*W4yqTIZzAWbcK4jQ4DM1g/MySQLandHadoopNov2011.pdf&ei=rdMDUZH2LcnjrAepyYCYDg&usg=AFQjCNFDquxh4GSuQarSZaXK8S6fRPPCDw&bvm=bv.41524429,d.bmk) is a standard guide to help you.
- This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632514/how-to-transfer-mysql-table-to-hive) talks about importing data to hive (which is just opposite to your requirement). But It will give you ideas about 'export' from hive too.